# Laravel reverse geocode the latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel-5, google-geocoder

Im using Laravel and this dependancy https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-geocoder to reverse geocode my latitude and longitude what I did first is to put a static lat and lng.
In my controller I have this:

```
  public function location(){
    $lat=40.714224;
    $lng=-73.961452;
    $param = array("latlng"=>"$lat,$lng");     
    $response = \Geocoder::geocode('json', $param);       
    return $response;
  }
```

This returns.

```
 {
 "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "277",
           "short_name" : "277",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
           "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings",
           "short_name" : "Kings",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.714232,
           "lng" : -73.9612889
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
              "lng" : -73.9599399197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
              "lng" : -73.96263788029151
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
     },
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
     }
```

Now what I want to do is to get the "formatted_address" of the results. Can you help me with this.

Comment: $json_obj = json_decode($response); $json_obj->results[0]->formatted_address should be fine or no?

Comment: thank you for your reply! I solved it already. I used that actually.